# Replicating RKConnectionDescription Without RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I'm in the process of removing RestKit from our iOS app. I'm able to get things that I want into Core Data, but they're not really connected.

For example, we have one network call that returns a list of "Category"s (which have a "categoryID" and a "categoryName"; "Category"s also map to-many "StoreLocation"s). We then have another network call that returns a list of "StoreLocation"s (which, among other things, have a "storeName", "storeID", "storeCategoryIDs"; "StoreLocation"s also map to-many "Category"s).

With RestKit, I could use a RKConnectionDescription to describe that "storeCategoryIDs" drove the relationship to-many "Category"s. With that, if I had a given Category object, I could easily determine which StoreLocations belonged to that category.

I'm struggling to see how to accomplishing this without any RestKit dependencies. I suppose I could, whenever I'm about to insert a new Category or new StoreLocation, fetch all of the opposite managed objects and do this manually, but I seem to be missing some component of Core Data that can do.

Comment: Why are you removing RestKit if it does things you want?

Comment: It's inadequate for general networking needs, so we're switching to plain AFNetworking 2.

Comment: In what way? It's built on AFN1 so you can access that when you need to. Do you require sessions?

Answer (score 0):

The main part you're missing is the predicate applied to the fetch and which uses the identification attributes to find the appropriate existing objects. You do need to run your own fetch as core data will not magically update one object if you create a different new object and insert it.

Comment: Is RestKit actually running a fetch each time (in this example) that the list of storeCategoryIDs is set?

Comment: It depends how you configure it. It also caches objects based on identification attrs if you ask it to.